# ruby create 1 dimensional array to 2 dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on the rails application I have the following array

```
["194K-001", "177K-STB", "17SH-LW9", "115L-T03"]
```

and i want to create it as follow

```
[["194K-001"], ["177K-STB"], ["17SH-LW9"], ["115L-T03"]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IRB:

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > ["194K-001", "177K-STB", "17SH-LW9", "115L-T03"].map{|a| [a]}
 => [["194K-001"], ["177K-STB"], ["17SH-LW9"], ["115L-T03"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) without argument:

```
["194K-001", "177K-STB", "17SH-LW9", "115L-T03"].zip
# => [["194K-001"], ["177K-STB"], ["17SH-LW9"], ["115L-T03"]]
```